# How to copy and paste in the command line Interface of Ubuntu Minimal?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, copy-paste, vmware-player

I've installed the 64bit edition of Ubuntu Minimal 14.04 in a VMware Player virtual machine. Ubuntu Minimal only has a CLI (Command Line Interface), which I like, but I can't figure out how to copy/paste in the terminal. I need paste especially, because some of the links I need to run are just too long to type manually.

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, but so far no luck. How can I copy/paste in the CLI?

Comment: I recommend installing ssh server, then connecting to the VM with the SSH client of your choice, e.g. PuTTY - this offers not only easy cut&paste, but also a resizable text console and other goodies.

Comment: This is a smart alternative. Thanks for input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### VMware Workstation 12.5.2 supports general paste (UPDATE)

By accident I noticed that the current version of Workstation (12.5.2) supports general paste. I mean paste anywhere including the Linux text console without need to have any VM tools installed. A similar function was available in Microsoft Virtual PC.

The function works by emulating key presses. This implies the following limitations:

- The keyboard layout of the VM must match the keyboard layout that VMware Workstation expects. Otherwise the characters on keys which differ will be entered wrongly.
- The expected keyboard layout in my case was "United States" though I use a different layout both in my host and guest machine.
- There does not seem to be a (simple) way how to change the expected keyboard layout.
- Only paste works this way. Copy works only the old way with the support of VMware tools.

I know about two ways how to invoke the function:

1. Have the VM window selected but the keyboard not grabbed (Ungrab using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> or select the VM window by clicking the VM tab.) then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
2. Have the VM window selected and use the function from the menu: **Edit** > **Paste**

There are additional limitations:

- There does not seem to be a shortcut using the VMware hot key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> which would allow using the function while the keyboard is grabbed.
- The function does not seem to be accessible from VMware 12 Player (version 12.5.2). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does not work and there is no **Paste** function in the menu.
- The function is described neither in the documentation nor in the release notes.

### The other and older products do not support paste outside of X Window System or without VM tools

This is a limitation of VMware products. Unfortunately most of them do not support copying and pasting in a text console of an operating system. The clipboard integration works only in the graphical user interface with working VMware Tools or open-vm-tools installed.

### SSH as an alternative solution

When I work with Linux virtual machines without GUI (almost all my Linux virtual machines) I use SSH access as Eugen Rieck suggested already. As he wrote this solution allows also other very useful features. I would certainly name longer and more easily usable scrollback buffer (without need to use terminal managers like `screen`).

Comment: Work like a charm!

Comment: Excellent idea suggesting SSH as an alternative solution, if all else fails.  Sometimes that's the best option anyway.  (Also upvoted Eugen's comment.)

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>Control+Shift+C</kbd> to copy, and use <kbd>Control+Shift+V</kbd> to paste.

References

1. http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-cut-copy-and-paste-in-the-terminal-in-ubuntu
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761807/copy-and-paste-from-terminal-with-keyboard-in-linux-ubuntu

Comment: This works in the GUI (X Window System). But the OP explicitly asks about Linux installation with command line only (i.e. no GUI installed).